# Exclude default font embed in RDLC render to PDF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, winforms, pdf, fonts, rdlc

I try to render RDLC report to PDF file and the size of the file generated is larger than normal. After some research i found the PDF generated have embedded font:
.....
9 0 obj
<< /Filter /FlateDecode  /Length 52986 /Length1 194264 >>
stream
.....

When i generate PDFs and save to disk with the same method and the same code one PDF have the size: 6.82 KB and other 109 KB.

The PDFs is identically if i open with Adobe Acrobat.

**Solution 1:**

I generate the PDF in MVC 4 application with "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" version 11.
I try to use "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms" library in the same MVC application to see if the size decreases but no result.

**Failed**

**Solutin 2:**

I search in RDLC file with notepad if exist something about fonts but not exist, only font size, if is bold but not some name.

**Failed**

The small PDF font property:
[image: Small PDF]

The large PDF font property:
[image]

My question is: How to not embed default font in PDF rendered from RDLC?

Answer (score 5):

It turns out we merely needed to add a key to the DeviceInfo.xml:

```
<DeviceInfo>
<EmbedFonts>None</EmbedFonts>
</DeviceInfo>
```

I found [the answer here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariae/archive/2010/04/12/how-to-disable-this-font-embedding-in-reporting-services-2005-service-pack-3.aspx).

Comment: yes absolutely. this should be the accepted answer. For `ReportViewer.WebForms`, this can also be done from code by passing the whole DeviceInfo xml tag as a string as the `deviceInfo` parameter to the `Render` function. Successfully tested with an rdlc that consisted of nothing but a label in Calibri Light, with embedding 155 KB, without embedding 5 KB.

Answer (score 0):

According to [How to embed a Font in a PDF with RDLC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725226/how-to-embed-a-font-in-a-pdf-with-rdlc) you must meet these requirements:

> - Font must be marked as embedding allowed
> - Font must be of type TrueType

This is similar to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255291.aspx#FontRequirements) on font embedding when exporting to a PDF File from Report Builder and SSRS:

> - Font embedding privileges are granted by the font author. Installed    fonts include a property that indicates whether the font author
>     intends to allow embedding a font in a document. If the property
>     value is EMBED_NOEMBEDDING, the font is not embedded in the PDF file. 
>     For more information, see "TTGetEmbeddingType" on msdn.microsoft.com.
> - The Font is TrueType.
> - Fonts are referenced by visible items in a report. If a font is    referenced by an item that has the Hidden property set to True, the
>     font is not needed to display rendered data and will not be included
>     in the file. Fonts are embedded only when they are needed to display
>     the rendered report data.

So if you do not meet these requirements, your font should not be embedded.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't use **Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms** in ASP.NET MVC. 
Rather just call your report server and get the report needed.

```
public async Task<FileStreamResult> GenerateReport()
{

    CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
    credentialCache.Add(new Uri("http://domainORipaddress"), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential(
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"],
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"]
    ));

    Stream report = null;
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentialCache }))
    { 
        //put the desired timeout here if needed to cancel the task
        httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);
        report = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync("reportUrl");
    }

    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", reportName));
    return File(reportPath, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
}
```

Reference: [SQL Server Reporting Service with ASP.NET MVC](http://webstackoflove.com/sql-server-reporting-service-with-asp-net-mvc/)

Font embedding was introduced:

**SQL Server 2008 Cumulative Update 1** (full font embedding and subsetting for Unicode characters)

**SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 3** (limited to non ANSI characters)

Reference: [Do You Unicode in PDF?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/10/27/unicode-in-pdf-font-embedding.aspx)

> Font embedding does no longer matter what version of a font is installed on a client - the documents can be viewed the same way regardless of client operating systems, font versions, and client PDF viewer.

So when you disable fonts embedding you are **basically reverting back to the old behavior**.

How do disable:

1. Open the **RSreportserver.config** file under the path: **RS Installation Folder\Reporting Services\ReportServer**

Reference: [Modify a Reporting Services Configuration File (RSreportserver.config)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630448.aspx)

1. Find the following

   ```
       <Extension Name="PDF" Type="    
       Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.PdfReport,
       Microsoft.ReportingServices.ImageRendering"/>
   ```
2. Add the following

   ```
    <Configuration>
      <DeviceInfo>
         <EmbedFonts>None</EmbedFonts>
      </DeviceInfo>
     </Configuration>
   ```
3. You would need to do an **IISReset** (IISReset stops and restarts the entire web server (including non-ASP.NET apps) to set the changes.

Reference: [How to disable this Font embedding in Reporting Services 2005 Service Pack 3?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariae/archive/2010/04/12/how-to-disable-this-font-embedding-in-reporting-services-2005-service-pack-3.aspx)

Comment: i use Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms because i use the same code in winform application and i get the same result on generate pdf.